# Python - need to extract certain parts of an array

Tags: python

I have 2 lists: x_data , y_data

both are 86400 (x_data is time in hours)
I want to be able to take out of my array the entries for x from 7 - 14 hours, and the corresponding values in y_data.

I've done

```
for i, j in enumerate(x_data):
        if ( j < 7 & j > 14): 
           print i, j
```

it doesn't work. I don't really know what to do. I have started trying to use python since this morning (trying to use it instead of IDL)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need for loo to extract. Just do this:

```
print x_data[7:15]
```

There is no array in python. Python has list, you read more about list [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: This only works if the indexes are equal to hours and if the data is sorted accordingly which is not automatically the case.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data):
    if 7 < x < 14:
        print(x, y)
```

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract the values into a separate list:

```
extract = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data) if 7 < x < 14]
```

With what you are doing:

```
for i, j in enumerate(x_data):
```

on each iteration, `j` is an element from `x_data` and `i` is its index. You can use this to access `y_data`:

```
     if 7 < j < 14:
         print(j, y_data[i])
```

but it is neater to `zip` the two lists together.

Answer (score 0):

In python, the operator is not `&` it is `and`

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on exactly how the data is formatted.

You say you have 86400 elements, so I guess it's one element per second. If so, something like:

```
start = 7 * 3600 # 7 hours
end = 14 * 3600  # and 14 hours
x_slice = x_data[start:end]
y_slice = y_data[start:end]
```

This, however, requires that x_data is sorted in increasing time.

If that is not the case, you would have to do some looping over the two arrays in parallel (the `zip`-based method mentioned by jonrsharpe looks like a likely starting point).